# How to get pull request key, source and target branch in Bamboo 6.6.3?

Tags: bamboo

When a PR is created in Bitbucket Bamboo creates a build. In version 6.6.3 the following variables are not available

```
bamboo.repository.pr.key
bamboo.repository.pr.sourceBranch
bamboo.repository.pr.targetBranch
```

I need these values in order to pass them to Sonar for PR analysis. What is the workaround to get the above values?

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using a Bamboo Spec Yaml.**  You can use it in two ways.

Please be aware: The condition `bamboo.repository.pr.key` will only appear if the trigger/request come from a `Pull request`. You may not see the variables in the log if this conditions do not match.

**Option 1.** You have a spec file

```yaml
version: 2
plan:
  project-key: EXAMPLE
  plan-key: PLAN
  name: Example Plan
  stages:
    - stage:
        name: Build and Test
        jobs:
          - job:
              name: Build
              tasks:
                - script:
                    interpreter: SHELL
                    scripts:
                      - |-
                        #!/usr/bin/env bash
                        echo "Build script goes here"

                        # NOTE In BASH you can replace the (.) to (_)  
                        # The variable bamboo.repository.pr.key
                        # Can now be used as bamboo_repository_pr_key
                        IS_PULL_REQUEST="${bamboo_repository_pr_key}"
                        echo "PULL Request ID $IS_PULL_REQUEST" 
                        
                    description: My Task that prints A pull request ID
```

**The Option 2**. You can add a Variable condition in you task itself and not as a script, in de code bellow you can see the key value `conditions:variables:matchs`
where we add a `repository.pr.key` without bamboo keyword. That is the trick.

```yaml
version: 2
plan:
  project-key: EXAMPLE
  plan-key: PLAN
  name: Example Plan
  stages:
    - stage:
        name: Build and Test
        jobs:
          - job:
              name: Build
              tasks:
                - script:
                    interpreter: SHELL
                    scripts:
                      - |-
                        #!/usr/bin/env bash
                        echo "Build script goes here"

                        # NOTE In BASH you can replace the (.) to (_)  
                        # The variable bamboo.repository.pr.key
                        # Can now be used as bamboo_repository_pr_key
                        IS_PULL_REQUEST="${bamboo_repository_pr_key}"
                        echo "PULL Request ID $IS_PULL_REQUEST" 
                        
                    description: My task that runs only with  repository.pr.key has values
                    conditions:
                      - variable:
                          matches:
                            repository.pr.key: '^[0-9]+$'
```

This is a YAML file which defines a CI/CD Pipeline using Atlassian Bamboo. Here is an overview of the file:

- The version of the pipeline definition format being used is `2`.
- The `plan` section includes information about the Bamboo plan, such as its project key, plan key, name, etc.
- The `stages` attribute contains one or more stages where each stage can contain one or more jobs.
- In this case, there is only one stage called `Build and Test`, and it has only one job called `Build`.
- Under `tasks`, the `script` section contains configuration for running scripts within the job.
- The `interpreter` attribute sets the interpreter to be used when executing the script.
- Under `scripts`, there is an example build script that echoes "Build script goes here".
- The next few lines demonstrate how to assign the value of the variable `bamboo_repository_pr_key` to another variable called `IS_PULL_REQUEST` and then print it.
- Further, there is a `description` field which describes the task that runs only when the variable `repository.pr.key` is set to a numerical value (regex: `'^[0-9]+$'`).

That's a brief explanation of the given YAML file. Let me know if you have any other questions!